# Connect-MsolService : An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to connect the Connect-MsolService from UAT enviornemnt which as Proxy configuration. We have set the proxy using netsh winhttp. My proxy has http://myproxy:8080 the same configured in IE as well. We able to access the internet. But when I using powerhshell to connect-MsolService getting the below error

I set the proxy before calling the command. I used proxy accessType and passed to Session Option. Nothing worked.

```
$credential = get-credential "idms@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com"
$sessionoption = New-PSSessionOption -SkipCACheck -SkipCNCheck -SkipRevocationCheck
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell-liveid -Credential $LiveCred   -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
```

It should connect and query the data. But getting error

```
Connect-MsolService : An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc. This 
could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server 
(possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService –Credential $LiveCred -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], CommunicationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService

Connect-MsolService : Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.
At line:1 char:1
+ Connect-MsolService –Credential $LiveCred -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], MicrosoftOnlineException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.ConnectMsolService
```

Comment: As an aside: I think it should be `$LiveCred = get-credential "idms@mycompany.onmicrosoft.com"`

Comment: try to import the IE proxy settings using: `netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie` then retry... also do you use Proxy Authentication?

Comment: we did the same and we also tried invoke-webrequest -Proxy http://myproxy:8080 -ProxyUseDefaultCredentials https://provisioningapi.microsoftonline.com/provisioningwebservice.svc this return he underlying connection was closed an unexpected error occured on receiving

Comment: I able to connect after setting SecurityProtocol TLS1.1.